# Why this is variable does not work? Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am writing the following code below, which basically takes the data from the current date to a PHP file to handle in jQuery. Until here everything well. But I'm not understand why I can not have a new value of the `total` variable after it picks the value coming PHP file.

```
day.each(function () {

        var $this = $(this);
        var the_index = $this.index();
        var the_date = $this.find('h3.date').html().substr(0,2);
        var the_day = $this.find('h3.day');

        /*THIS VARIABLE*/   
        var total = 0;

        $.get('trd/datetime.php', function (date) {

            if(that.hasClass('list-'+date.day)) {
                weekList.find('.item.list-'+date.day).addClass('active');
            }

            total = date.firstDate;

        }, 'json');

        console.log(total);


    });
```

I don't know if my english helps, but, please, tell me what wrong I'm doing!

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the alert @Asad. I will read this questions and see if it works for me too. If not, let you know.

Comment: @Asad thank you very much! That explanation has worked for me. See how I fixed the problem:

I created a callback function `changeWeekDates()`, where I passed the value `date.firstDate` to execute, instead to execute in the AJAX call.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The `.get` call is asynchronous -- the stuff inside it runs *after* your `console.log` statement.

You probably want to use a callback, which you invoke from inside the `.get` handler:

```
$.get('trd/datetime.php', function (date) {
    // ...

    callback(total);
}, 'json');

function callback(total) {
    console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Suppose the variable `total` have to get a number value, coming from the PHP file. So, it is not updating the value of the variable, it remains zero. Could understand? ;-/

Comment: so long as your php serves valid json structured as you expect it then you pass your callback date.firstDate